# escape @ in host name of mysql when dropping a user

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a drop a user from my mysql server and the former admin created a very strange entry, user XXX @ €€s@€%.

So, the normal syntax:

```
drop user 'nick'@"€€s@€%";
```

does not work, and it complains about:

```
Malformed hostname (illegal symbol: '@')
```

Is there a way around it without the risk of messing up with existing users? This is my work's mysql server and I don't really want to experiment/change much, if possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Quote with backticks?

Comment: How do you mean @jarlh ? I tried drop user 'nick'@'€€s`@`€%'; and drop user 'nick'@'`€€s@€%`'; but none works.

Comment: <backtick> character before and after the username.

Comment: Maybe - drop user 'nick'@'€€s\@€%'; ?

Comment: I tried what @Anton suggested initially, also same response.

Comment: Do you have other users like 'nick'?

Comment: @jarlh, the username is not a problem, it's the hostname with the @ that makes mysql complain.

Comment: @Anton No, "nick" had 2 entries, and when I did a simple "DROP nick" it only removed one of them, leaving this one behind... Can I do something about this?

Comment: Ok, let's try this one - UPDATE mysql.user SET host='test' WHERE user='nick' and then DROP USER 'nick'@'test'

Comment: @Anton, you just made me realise how stupid I am :D  THAT was an excellent workaround!! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added solution based on comments

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET host='test' WHERE user='nick' 
DROP USER 'nick'@'test'
```